# How to overwrite blazor wasm IConfiguration with content of a json file?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Hello you guys out there,

this is my first question, please be kind.

I have a blazor webassembly client application. In there there is a class to hold configurations:

```
public sealed class AppConfiguration
{
  public string MeIsAString { get; set; } = "Hello World!";
}
```

In Program.cs a custom json file gets added to the WebAssemblyHostBuilder via WebAssemblyHostBuilder.Configuration.AddJsonStream():

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault();
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
var httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) };
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => httpClient);
builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(await (await httpClient.GetAsync("path-to-json-file")).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
```

The json file looks like this:

```
{
  "AppConfiguration": {
    "MeIsAString" : "different string",
  },
}
```

Reading the configuration from within the app via (Configuration is Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration):

```
var s = Configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>().MeIsAString; // s is now "Hello World!"
```

works fine.

My question is: Why is MeIsAString not overwritten with the content of the json file?

I've called Build() on whats returned by AddJsonStream() and tryed to add that to the configuration used by builder, but it does not override MeIsAString. When stepping through the code in Program.cs i noticed that one configuration provider is successfully registered. I also noticed that getting the config via Configuration.Get<>() does not work without AddJsonStream().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by myself.

The problem is, that `Configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>()` takes everything in between of the top level parenthesis in the json file and from that what matches members of `AppConfiguration` (this behaving is only valid if the json file isn't empty).

Because `AppConfiguration` has no member named `AppConfiguration`, the instance returned by `Configuration.Get<AppConfiguration>()` has values only from AppConfiguration.cs.

So removing `"AppConfiguration":{...}` from the json file or working with `Configuration.GetSection("AppConfiguration").Get<AppConfiguration>()` solves the issue.

Comment: You are allowed to tick it